# Cannot interpret this testflight crash report

Tags: objective-c, realm, crash-reports

Can anyone help me interpret this? I assume it is Realm related. However this method getFullName is only like:

```
- (NSString *)getFullName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}
```

Whereas self.firstName and lastName are properties of the FMUser object.

Here is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: CAAAA4B5-839F-4BE1-8FE9-831E48BAB2DA
Beta Identifier:     6831D34A-D895-4E76-AAAE-4C5FCD9C1537
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,6
Process:             FollowMe [1904]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B77E6F0C-21EF-4525-906A-94E70A2313D2/FollowMe.app/FollowMe
Identifier:          com.followme.aero.FollowMe
Version:             2.5.39.1 (2.5.39)
AppStoreTools:       11C29
AppVariant:          1:iPhone10,6:13
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.followme.aero.FollowMe [811]


Date/Time:           2020-02-13 15:30:52.2538 +0100
Launch Time:         2020-02-13 14:41:55.0135 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.03.03
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18eccea48 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18e9f5fa4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   Realm                           0x1052ef698 RLMGetString(RLMObjectBase*, unsigned long) + 184 (RLMObject_Private.hpp:39)
3   FollowMe                        0x10418ed98 -[FMUser getFullName] + 44 (FMUser.m:202)
4   FollowMe                        0x1041fe42c -[FMCenterViewController updatedVariableHeader] + 68 (FMCenterViewController.m:1216)
5   FollowMe                        0x1042043c0 -[FMCenterViewController iAppProductStatusChanged:] + 84 (FMCenterViewController.m:1928)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x18ec2a288 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20 (CFNotificationCenter.c:787)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18ec2a2d0 ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 64 (CFNotificationCenter.c:175)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x18ec29630 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 368 (CFNotificationCenter.c:198)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x18ec292e8 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 104 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1371)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x18eba559c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1416 (CFXNotificationRegistrarOld.m:168)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18ec28c38 _CFXNotificationPost + 1244 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1359)
12  Foundation                      0x18ef850c8 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60 (NSNotification.m:576)
13  FollowMe                        0x1041b854c __51-[FMIAPHelper callAPIRequestInAppPurchase:restore:]_block_invoke + 888 (FMIAPHelper.m:363)
14  FollowMe                        0x10415eb20 __68-[FMAPIClient requestInAppPurchaseWithParams:withSuccess:andFailed:]_block_invoke + 56 (FMAPIClient.m:412)
15  FollowMe                        0x10415b818 __47-[FMAPIClient POST:parameters:success:failure:]_block_invoke + 324 (FMAPIClient.m:99)
16  AFNetworking                    0x104fc669c __84-[AFHTTPSessionManager dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:URLString:parameters:success:failure:]_block_in... + 116 (AFHTTPSessionManager.m:0)
17  AFNetworking                    0x104fd9308 __72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke_2.68 + 144 (AFURLSessionManager.m:202)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x18e99a610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1408)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x18e99b184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x18e97e1c8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 608 (inline_internal.h:2470)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x18ec4c5e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1749)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x18ec475d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004 (CFRunLoop.c:3069)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x18ec46adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
24  GraphicsServices                0x198be7328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
25  UIKitCore                       0x192d5463c UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4773)
26  FollowMe                        0x1042848dc main + 88 (main.m:14)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x18ead0360 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eac5ec4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e5724 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 216 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018e9358c0 __abort + 112 (abort.c:147)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018e935850 abort + 112 (abort.c:118)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ea8e7d4 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ea8e9c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:66)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018e9f6258 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
7   FollowMe                        0x000000010429c418 CLSTerminateHandler() + 352 (CLSException.mm:310)
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ea9b304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ea9b29c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:87)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e99b198 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:498)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e97e1c8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 608 (inline_internal.h:2470)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4c5e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1749)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec475d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004 (CFRunLoop.c:3069)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec46adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
15  GraphicsServices                0x0000000198be7328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
16  UIKitCore                       0x0000000192d5463c UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4773)
17  FollowMe                        0x00000001042848dc main + 88 (main.m:14)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018ead0360 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa4634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa3aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4c288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec473a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec46adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   Foundation                      0x000000018ef86784 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018ef86664 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000192dece80 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152 (UIEventFetcher.m:637)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018f0b709c __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa4634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa3aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   FollowMe                        0x000000010428a088 CLSMachExceptionServer + 104 (CLSMachException.c:179)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eac79a4 kevent + 8
1   Realm                           0x00000001052ccd78 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 184 (external_commit_helper.cpp:199)
2   Realm                           0x00000001052cd0c4 std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::Ex... + 32 (external_commit_helper.cpp:159)
3   Realm                           0x00000001052cd258 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, st... + 64 (type_traits:4302)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa4634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa3aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4c288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec473a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec46adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000191f104e8 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 192 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f0b709c __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa4634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eaa3aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4c288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec473a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec46adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   AVFAudio                        0x000000019b829c1c GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:91)
6   AVFAudio                        0x000000019b87ad60 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 204 (CAPThread.cpp:286)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eac5c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e7094 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 672 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018eb187a8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:287)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da6938c void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::uni... + 108 (condition_variable:204)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da6cd5c bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 200 (condition_variable:213)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da6ca44 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 12 (Scavenger.cpp:384)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da6dd50 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, st... + 40 (type_traits:4361)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eac5c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e7094 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 672 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da2dafc WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 144 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:541)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da139a8 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::Scope... + 2040 (ParkingLot.cpp:596)
4   WebCore                         0x0000000196994bf0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184 (ParkingLot.h:80)
5   WebCore                         0x0000000196c26248 SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 664 (Condition.h:115)
6   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019ac9cda0 CallDelegate(void (*)(), WebView*, objc_object*, objc_selector*, objc_object*, objc_object*) + 124 (WebDelegateImplementationCaching.mm:692)
7   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019acb5250 WebFrameLoaderClient::dispatchDidFinishLoading(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, unsigned long) + 236 (WebFrameLoaderClient.mm:555)
8   WebCore                         0x0000000197a00214 WebCore::ResourceLoadNotifier::didFinishLoad(WebCore::ResourceLoader*, WebCore::NetworkLoadMetric... + 120 (ResourceLoadNotifier.cpp:163)
9   WebCore                         0x0000000197a13100 WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(WebCore::NetworkLoadMetrics const&) + 752 (SubresourceLoader.cpp:670)
10  WebCore                         0x0000000197a0b218 WebCore::ResourceLoader::didFinishLoading(WebCore::ResourceHandle*) + 148 (ResourceLoader.cpp:705)
11  WebCore                         0x00000001981f0208 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<-[WebCoreResourceHandleAsOperationQueueDelegate connectionDidFinishL... + 68 (WebCoreResourceHandleAsOperationQueueDelegate.mm:321)
12  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da07b5c WTF::dispatchFunctionsFromMainThread() + 316 (Function.h:79)
13  Foundation                      0x000000018f0b7224 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 232 (NSThread.m:807)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4ca00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1922)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4c958 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80 (CFRunLoop.c:1956)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4c0f0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180 (CFRunLoop.c:1992)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec4723c __CFRunLoopRun + 1080 (CFRunLoop.c:2882)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ec46adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
19  WebCore                         0x0000000196c2a0f0 RunWebThread(void*) + 612 (WebCoreThread.mm:626)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eac5c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e7094 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 672 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da2dabc WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 80 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:518)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da139a8 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::Scope... + 2040 (ParkingLot.cpp:596)
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019ac82d84 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184 (ParkingLot.h:80)
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019ac859b8 std::__1::unique_ptr<WTF::Function<void ()>, std::__1::default_delete<WTF::Function<void ()> > > ... + 168 (MessageQueue.h:153)
6   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019ac8509c WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 68 (MessageQueue.h:131)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da2b734 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256 (Function.h:79)
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019da2d2a4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:200)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9e9d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e9ed76c thread_start + 8
```

Comment: Well, something is probably nil. Could be the FMUser, could be the first name or last name, I'm not sure. I guess I think it's one of the names, since otherwise we wouldn't have gotten this far.

Comment: There's not enough code in the question to really determine the issue. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)